# jQuery mobile does not work properly in phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

For some reason Jquery mobile will not load when I build the app and put it on my android but if I run it on an Emulator it looks and runs great. Please Help Me. Is there any extra steps that I need to take to make it work or anything?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #container
            {
                margin: 8px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        var xmlhttp;

        window.onload=function()
        {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
            //init();
        }

        function init()
        {
            document.getElementById('btnHitServer').addEventListener('click', getServer, false);
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = receiveServer;
        }

        function getServer()
        {
            xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://app.mafialife.com/?email_debug=1', false);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function receiveServer()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
               // console.log(json);
                document.getElementById('Server').innerHTML = json.value.joke;
            }
        }

        </script>
        <title>Hit Server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <h2>Connect To Server</h2>
        <button id="btnHitServer">Hit Server</button>
        <p>Press the button to Connect To Server</p>
        <div id="Server"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really be downloading the JavaScript and CSS for JQuery and JQuery mobile and making them local resources in your Cordova project.  Then adjust your  and  tags to point to the local versions.

Not including these files locally will cause your app to not be able to start up and work should the device be offline, and will cause unnecessary performance issues as the app tries to download these files remotely on startup.

If you are using Cordova 5, the remote loading of JS and CSS on startup is also what's probably stopping your app on a real device, the [Content Security Policy](http://content-security-policy.com/) meta tag would need to be configured to allow remote JS and CSS loads.  However as per my previous comments you want to bundle these locally in the app somewhere in your www folder (say in css and js subfolders depending on how you have your project structured) as loading them remotely is not a best practice for the reasons I stated.

Comment: So I now am storing the jQuery locally but It still will not load when running the app.

Comment: Did you add a deviceready event listener and start your app in the callback function to that?  Cordova isn't ready until that event fires.

Comment: I am not sure. How would I do that exactly?

Comment: Sorry looks like you have one, did you also move your CSS for JQuery mobile locally?

Comment: Yeah I moved it all to local. It still doesn't load. Also for some reason I am not able to hit the server with the GET function I am using.

Comment: If you're on Cordova 5 you may need to implement a Content Security Policy that allows GET requests to your server from Cordova, article here helps explain that: http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/ - if you are on iOS 9 you will also need the App Transport Security part of this post.